# Solution of Einstein's field equation for local energy density

Tags: general-relativity, de-sitter-spacetime

If there is a uniform positive energy density present in a patch of space-time, what would be the metric describing the patch? a de-Sitter patch? What would be the gravitational potential felt by a mass in that region?

Comment: Thinking globally rather than locally, I’m pretty sure that you need more than just uniform positive energy density to get a de Sitter spacetime; you also need negative pressure of equal magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

Under the approximation of spherical symmetry, the FLRW metric describes any homogeneous patch. Note that in general such a patch would not remain static for the same reason that the universe should not be static. The Friedmann equations precisely describe how the patch would evolve.

The gravitational potential is a Newtonian idea, but we can generalize it to this picture pretty easily. Suppose the patch has energy density $\rho(t)$ and pressure $p(t)$. For a spherical region of radius $r$ inside our patch, the second Friedmann equation says that
$$
\frac{d^2r}{dt^2} = -\frac{4\pi G}{3}[\rho(t)+3p(t)]r.
$$
That must also be the acceleration of a test mass at radius $r$ with respect to the (arbitrary) origin. But this is just a harmonic oscillator with potential
$$
\Phi(r) = \frac{2\pi G}{3}[\rho(t)+3p(t)] r^2.
$$